# How to display data from 3 maps in one table in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I have three maps having data in it. 
How can i display it in a table in jsp page.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate each map using `<c:forEach>`

```
<table>
<c:forEach items="#{map1}" var="item1">             
   <tr>       
  <td><c:out value="#{item1.key}" /></td>
  <td><c:out value="#{item1.value}" </td>
  </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Beat me to it by a matter of seconds :D +1

Comment: i have done that but formatting in table is not correct. The values from second and third map are shown in row and i want them in a column.

Answer (score 0):

Merge three Map in to one .

```
    Map<String, Integer> map1 = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    Map<String, Integer> map2 = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    Map<String, Integer> map3 = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    Map<String, Integer> combinedMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    combinedMap.putAll(map1);
    combinedMap.putAll(map2);
    combinedMap.putAll(map3);
```

Then Iterate on `combinedMap`.

```
    <c:forEach items="#{combinedMap}" var="item1">
```

Comment: <c:forEach var="var1" items="${term1}">
                        <c:if var=""
                     <tr><td>${var1.key} </td>  <td>${var1.value}</td></tr>
 </c:forEach><c:forEach var="var2" items="${term2}">
                    <td>${var2.value}</td>
                </c:forEach>
                <c:forEach var="var3" items="${term3}">
                   <td>${var3.value}</td></tr>
                </c:forEach>

Comment: This answer assumes all the three maps have the same type of name value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

There are more than one way to accomplish this (one of them):

By using JSP Standard Tag Library (JSTL) `c:forEach` Tag as follows:

```
 <c:set value="${sessionScope.sessionObject.map1}" var="map1">
 <c:set value="${sessionScope.sessionObject.map1}" var="map2">
 <c:set value="${sessionScope.sessionObject.map1}" var="map3">

<c:forEach items="${map1}" var="item1">             
   <tr>       
  <td><c:out value="${item1.key}" /></td>
  <td><c:out value="${item1.value}" </td>
  </tr>
</c:forEach>
<c:forEach items="${map2}" var="item1"> .... etc
```

Or join them in one map and then iterate.

Comment: the data from second and third map will go in <td>. how to do this.

Comment: my answer says it all. did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem i used the MultiMap from apache commons collections.
This can also be solved if i create a DTO for data to be sent on jsp.